# Distance between CBCentralManager and CBPeripheralManager

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I follow the tutorial at this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741) to create a simple bluetooth LE system. 
Now what I want to do is to calculate the distance between the sender and the receiver of the packets. 
I see that in the following method `- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI` will be returned the RSSI value. What I'm searching for, is the Txpower value to calculate the distance because I found on the web a formula that requires RSSI and Txpower level to make the calculation.
I tried to search on Apple developer guide, and i found that Txpower level value will be contained inside the `advertisementData` with the `CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey` key, but i tried to Debug my example and the `advertisementData` never contains that key.
What I'm mistaking?

Comment: You know that's you'll get only a "theorical" distance? RSSI&Tx are used in iBeacon, the Tx characteristic giving the "RSSI" at 1 meter. But still, if a person appears between the two, you'll get wrong distance.

Comment: Yes i know ! In fact i want only an hypothetical distance, but i can't do the calculation because i can't retrieve the tx characteristic